# Why is this code is generating an infinite recursion in SML if it has a base case?

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj, infinite-recursion

I wrote the following code in SML with the NJ Compiler:

```
fun all_answers (f, xs) = 
    let 
        fun aux(accu, xs_left) = 
            case xs of
               [] => SOME accu
            | x::xs' => case f(x) of 
                          NONE => NONE
                        | SOME y => aux(accu@y, xs')
    in
        aux([], xs)
    end
```

It works well for this tests:

```
val testAll1 = all_answers ((fn x => if x = 1 then SOME [x] else NONE), []) = SOME []
val testAll2 = all_answers ((fn x => if x = 1 then SOME [x] else NONE), [2,3,4,5,6,7]) = NONE
```

However, something weird happens with this test:

```
val testAll3 = all_answers ((fn x => if x = 1 then SOME [x] else NONE), [1]) = SOME [1]
```

After running the program, the terminal goes on forever.

I defined the tail recursion and used the pattern-match with `xs'` to reach the tail.

Moreover, I defined the base case to end the recursion so that if `xs` is `[]` then the auxiliary function returns `SOME accumulator`

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you intending to case on `xs` in `aux` instead of `xs_left`?

Comment: Yeah. It was something silly. I thought it was something hard. I should get more sleep. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kopecs pointed out, this is caused by `case xs of` when you want `case xs_left of`.

Here is a cleaned up (whitespace, naming) version of your function:

```
fun all_answers (f, ys) =
    let
        fun aux (accu, xs) =
            case xs of
                 [] => SOME accu
               | x::xs' => case f x of
                                NONE => NONE
                              | SOME y => aux (accu@y, xs)
    in
        aux ([], ys)
    end
```

There are at least two things you could do to simplify the way this function is made. (1) Perform the `case xs of` inside the function pattern rather than in a nested case-of. (2) Remove the inner `aux` function and simply do the recursion in the outer function, at the expense of some tail-recursion

The first simplification might look like:

```
fun all_answers2 (f, ys) =
    let
        fun aux (accu, []) = SOME accu
          | aux (accu, x::xs) =
               case f x of
                    NONE => NONE
                  | SOME y => aux (accu@y, xs)
    in
        aux ([], ys)
    end
```

And the second might look like:

```
fun all_answers' (f, []) = SOME []
  | all_answers' (f, x::xs) =
      case f x of
           NONE => NONE
         | SOME ys => case all_answers' (f, xs) of
                           NONE => NONE
                         | SOME result => SOME (ys @ result)
```

This shows a pattern: Whenever you have

```
case f x of
     NONE => NONE
   | SOME y => case g y of
                    NONE => NONE
                  | SOME z => ...
```

then you have a programming pattern that could be abstracted out with a function.

There is already a standard library function that is made for this called [`Option.map`](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/option.html#SIG:OPTION.map:VAL), so you could write:

```
fun all_answers3 (f, ys) =
    let
        fun aux (accu, []) = SOME accu
          | aux (accu, x::xs) =
              Option.map (fn y => aux (accu@y, xs))
                         (f x)
    in
        aux ([], ys)
    end
```

Try and play around with this function in the REPL:

```
- Option.map (fn y => y + 2) NONE;
> val it = NONE : int option
- Option.map (fn y => y + 2) (SOME 2);
> val it = SOME 4 : int option
```

---

Taking this in another direction, rather than an inner function:

```
(* Alternative to Option.map: *)
fun for NONE _ = NONE
  | for (SOME x) f = f x

(* Equivalent to Option.mapPartial with "flipped" arguments: *)
fun for opt f = Option.mapPartial f opt

fun all_answers'' (f, []) = SOME []
  | all_answers'' (f, x::xs) =
      for (f x) (fn ys =>
        for (all_answers'' (f, xs)) (fn result =>
          SOME (ys @ result)))
```

This style is more Haskell-like because it follows a monadic design pattern.

Comment: My problem was simple. However, your answer was great. Thank you for writing it. This is a deep and valuable answer. I learned a lot from reading it.

Comment: Probably also ought to be pointed out your alternative to `Option.map` is just `Option.mapPartial` with flipped argument order.

Comment: @kopecs: You have a point. I will make a small change.